# How to decode .p format file or how to convert .p file to .m file?

Tags: matlab

How to decode .p format file Or how to convert .p file to .m file? Is there anyway to do that? Somebody can help me ? I have tried a lot of ways to decode .p file, but all tries failed.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/129728

Comment: "Crack" has the meaning that you intend to perform dishonest work with the decoded file. Be careful with your language in future posts.

Comment: @rayryeng Thx for your recommendation.